# A tough Limit problem.

Tags: limits

If I need $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg(1-\bigg(1-\frac1{N^{\frac t{2m-t}}}\bigg)^{\binom mt}\Bigg)^{m/t}=1$ then is it *sufficient* for $\frac mt<\frac{N^{\frac t{2m-t}}}{g(N)}<N^{\frac t{2m-t}}<\frac{t}{2m-t}{N^{\frac t{2m-t}}}{\log N}<\binom mt$ at any growing function $g(N)$ to hold?

I checked few examples in mathematica. It seems to make sense.

How fast or slow can $m$, $t$ and $\frac mt$ grow as a function of $N$?

Comment: Are $m,t$ functions of $N$? How are they defined?

Comment: yeah $m$ and $t$ are functions of $N$.

Comment: What if $m=0$? then ${m\choose t}$ is not defined, but the limit is still $0$

Comment: @Mastrem $m>0$.